# how to customize contact form 7 plugin for wordpress from back-end

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7

im working on a booking tours website, and for this tours there is a specific conditions that the normal CF7 don't have, for an example if the price for one person is 100$ and for two persons is 150$, and picking hotels 4 or 5start...etc, so as you can see i need a specific algorithm here to work on CF7, also after all this i need to show the final price to the client and have it pay it with paypal. i already tried many bookings plugins but none of them do the right job.
i can code the algorithm with js or php but i'm just a beginner with WP.
so any ideas any suggestions from you guys i will appreciate it.

Comment: As per your request you may need Gravity form rather then CF7

Comment: @lakshmanrajput thank you for your help, it's the right choice

Answer (score 0):

Please use gravity form plugin. if you want add conditions.

Thank you